# How to deal with the Nonetype object have no attribute 'shape' error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 2500 columns.
To get train and target I did:

```
target=data['Col2'].values
train=data.drop('Col2',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

but when I tried to get shape of train data by `print(train.shape)` it is showing

> 'Nonetype object has no attribute 'shape'

How to make this training data as dataframe, or how to deal with this error?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - please tag responsibly

Answer (score 2):

The error is because `train` is `None` in your code. You don't want to deal with the fact that Nonetype does not have that attribute - you want to check why `train` is `None`.

The command `train=data.drop('Col2',axis=1,inplace=True)` does not return anything - it returns `None` and modifies `data` inplace.

You want to change it to `train=data.drop('Col2',axis=1)`.

Check out [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) of `.drop`, they explain in there.